# Unzipping bz2 file

Tags: linux, unix, optimization, compression

I have the following command to open a tbz file:

```
# pricing20150304.tbz
tar xpj -C {tarball} {files_to_unarchive}
```

The compressed file is about 15 GB and when it is expanded it is about 500GB or so. This operation on an ec2-4x-large operation takes roughly 1h40m.

Is there a way to optimize this operation? What would be the fastest way to do the above operation?

Comment: So, I expected this question to be a "let's insert unneeded tags and see if they edit or do something else with it" test when it came up in the review queue.  Since it apparently wasn't, was there a reason why you tagged it with python?  More usefully... have you run any perf measurements to see whether this is bottlenecking on I/O, CPU, etc.?  If I/O bound (which would be my first guess for what I'm assuming is an M4-XL or similar) Have you tried changing the provisioned IO to be the highest (and therefore most expensive) to see if the boost makes it worth it (and/or are you already using it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple possibilities come to mind.  First off, bzip2 is pretty slow, so if you can use a different algorithm you might want to consider doing so.  Assuming you still want a fairly high ratio, LZHAM and Brotli might be good choices; they take longer to compress but are *much* faster when it comes to decompression, and IIRC both come with multi-threaded decompressors.  There are lots of choices, and they all have [different trade-offs](https://quixdb.github.io/squash-benchmark/?machine=peltast) between compression speed, decompression speed, and ratio.

If a different algorithm isn't an option, you might want to consider using [pbzip2](http://compression.ca/pbzip2/) instead of bzip2.  Something like `pbzip2 -dc infile.tar.bz2 | tar x`.